# Makes PDF readonly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to display PDF in Read-only format so website visitors can read PDF but not allowing them to download or print or any other operation.

Anybody have such reference code?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, and not very practical as well:

- If you can view it in your browser, you already have downloaded the file.
- If you have it in your browser, there's nothing that can stop you from printing a screen capture of the file, so even while it is possible to create a PDF that isn't printable, it would be easily defeated.

Comment: thanks for reply   then any other way to manage pdf readonly when showing on website

Comment: Readonly means that you can't edit it. With Acrobat Pro you can accomplish that, as well as disable the print option, like @diedie2 stated. But you cannot prevent people from downloading something you want them to see, and like I stated: the inability to print a pdf is easily circumvented.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable the printing option in a PDF, this can be done by setting a password on the printing funtion and ofcourse not sharing the password.

If you google this you will find how to do this. [This Website](https://techwalla.com/content/disable-pdf-print-function) might already be a good start.
Note: you will need Acrobat Pro, wich is not free.

Keep in mind, like @Stephen already mentioned, people can make a screenshot or something similar and print it anyway.

Comment: thanks  but  if i want to show my content to user for reading only  then any other way rather than pdf